# Make UIView subview as default UIView for UIViewController with Storyboard

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have a multi-viewcontroller app.

The main view of the main VC is subclassed so I can use Core Graphics animations. It's called "animations" class.

On the storyboard, I add a UIView called "MainArea" as a subview of the "animations". I have a VC called "MainAreaVC". As you know it has a property of "view". How can I make the "MainArea" subview the default UIView of my "MainAreaVC"?

The other option is to just make the "MainArea" view a property of my "MainAreaVC" and use this. I just don't want the "MainAreaVC"'s default "view" property just hanging out doing nothing.

Comment: A possibly better way to achieve the functionality of `animations` and not run into this hierarchy conundrum is to use `extension` or `delegate`.

Comment: @LancelotdelaMare Can you provide example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `view` in a `UIViewController` is the bottom view: it is always the one at the root of the tree hierarchy, and appears behind everything else, possibly clipping subviews.

You can change the `view` **Class**, but no matter what you do, by design it must be at the root. If, somehow, you managed to point to one of your subviews, that subview would in essence become the root.

**Comment:**

You do not have to add a view of type `animations` containing another view of type `mainArea`. You can have 'MainArea`inherit from`animations`, and drag such`MainArea` in the storyboard.